# How to scan directories on production on Vercel (with Next.js)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I've developed a JS script to work as a sitemap.xml when accessed through the URL (eg: mydomain.com/sitemap.xml), which will list the pages of my project. When running on development (`yarn dev`) it works fine, also works when it runs after building and starting on my pc (`yarn build` & `yarn start`). The problem is that on Vercel it doesn't work, the error is:

```
[GET] /sitemap.xml
19:39:16:85
Function Status:
None
Edge Status:
500
Duration:
146.30 ms
Init Duration:
446.50 ms
Memory Used:
80 MB
info  - Loaded env from /var/task/.env.production
info  - Loaded env from /var/task/.env
2021-11-18T19:39:17.673Z    68ecb71f-eede-4cbd-81a9-5c677f11e556    ERROR   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/task/.next/server/pages/projects'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1047:3)
    at getServerSideProps (/var/task/.next/server/pages/sitemap.xml.js:38:56)
    at Object.renderToHTML (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:504:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async doRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1428:38)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1523:28
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache.js:63:36 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/var/task/.next/server/pages/projects',
  page: '/sitemap.xml'
}
RequestId: 68ecb71f-eede-4cbd-81a9-5c677f11e556 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

The piece of code on my `sitemap.xml.js` that does that work is:

```
const staticPagesProjects = fs
                .readdirSync({
                    development: 'src/pages/projects',
                    production: __dirname + '/projects',
                }[process.env.NODE_ENV])
                .filter((staticPagesProjects) => {
                    return regex.test(staticPagesProjects) && (staticPagesProjects != "index.html") && (staticPagesProjects != "404.html") && (staticPagesProjects != "500.html");
                })
                .map((staticPagePath) => {
                    return `${baseUrl}/projects/${staticPagePath.replace(".html", "")}`;
                });
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the path and why it works on my pc but not on Vercel? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, unfortunatly I didn't found the solution either, but I found a way that could help :

For the static page I added them manually in an array.

For the dynamic pages it worked by connecting to DB and fetching the pages in an array.

Since it has been a month now, did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by add it

```js
path.resolve(process.cwd(), "your folder")
```

This means you will figure out the current path of your source, not the built source